# Music doesn't stop if Looping(true)

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

i'm currently working with MediaPlayer in eclipse, i found out that if i'm looping the song i can not Pause it when i want. To be clear i will show you the code.

in OnCreate section

```
    ToggleButton unu = (ToggleButton)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ss);
    unu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // If the music is playing
            if(mp1.isPlaying())
                // Pause the music player
                mp1.pause();
            // If it's not playing
            else
                // Resume the music player
                mp1.setLooping(true);
                mp1.start();
        }
    });
```

Any ideas why i can't pause it?
i was trying something like this

```
            if(mp1.isPlaying())
                // Pause the music player
                mp1.pause();
                mp1.setLooping(false);
            // If it's not playing
            else
                // Resume the music player
                mp1.setLooping(true);
                mp1.start();
```

it gives me error saying: Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

Comment: Try it with brackets.

Comment: I see... missing brackets, missing brackets everywhere!

Comment: @Nfear, Th0rndike thank you, it works now but why without looping it worked without brackets?
  unu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp1.isPlaying()) 
                    mp1.pause(); 
                else
                    mp1.start(); 
            }
        });

Comment: Because only the first line after if will execute.

Comment: you might want to take a look at the [coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). Very helpful for avoiding syntax errors such as this.  Get these ingrained now, your code will be much more readable and it will become second nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Nfear said brackets where missing

```
       if(mp1.isPlaying()) {
            // Pause the music player
            mp1.pause();
            mp1.setLooping(false); }
        // If it's not playing
        else {
            // Resume the music player
            mp1.setLooping(true);
            mp1.start(); }
```

adding brackets solved the error